# Scope of imported macro-generated code in Elixir

Tags: functional-programming, macros, elixir

I am going through Saša Jurić's fantastic [series on macros](http://theerlangelist.com/article/macros_2), and while running the following piece of code, I encountered something that confused me:

```
defmodule Plug.Router do
  defmacro get(route, body) do
    quote do
      defp do_match("GET", unquote(route), var!(conn)) do
        unquote(body[:do])
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule MyRouter do
  import Plug.Router

  def match(type, route) do
    do_match(type, route, :dummy_connection)
  end

  get "/hello", do: {conn, "Hi!"}
  get "/goodbye", do: {conn, "Bye!"}

  MyRouter.match("GET", "/hello") |> IO.inspect
  MyRouter.match("GET", "/goodbye") |> IO.inspect
end
```

My questions are:

- in which module is the `do_match/3` function injected? Is it in the `Plug.Router` module, or in the `MyRouter` one? Further down in the article, it's mentioned that `use` and `require` inject the code in the caller's module. Is this valid for `import`ed macros too?
- where in Elixir's code should I look for the implementation of this behaviour?
- is there an easy way of inspecting the structure of a module after expansion? Something equivalent to `Macro.to_string/3`, but for `Module`s?

Comment: I'm unsure of the answers to your other questions but there's this from the docs: "Note that importing a module automatically requires it" (this comes from here: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html)  So I'd guess that import also injects the code into the caller's module as well.

Comment: Import does not inject any code into the caller module. It is purely a lexical construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions generated by the macro will be defined in `MyRouter`

If you `require` a module, its macros will be made available to the caller module. If you `import` a module, its macros and functions will additionally be accessible without having to use the module name as prefix. See the [getting started guide on alias, require and import](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html) for more details.

`require` and `import` are quite low level features of Elixir, so they are implemented in Erlang directly. A fair amount of the `import` and `require` logic can be found [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/9ac3c2e00d396add4837f10330df688ec18c31d3/lib/elixir/src/elixir_exp.erl#L80-L117).

I am not aware of a way of introspecting these things, since macros basically leave no trace in the compiled code. It's part of the beauty of macros that they will not introduce any additional overhead to your code. However, you can check which functions are in a module after macro expansion with `MyRouter.__info__(:functions)`

Comment: You can introspect them by doing `IO.inspect __ENV__`. `__ENV__` contains the compile time environment. You can find requires, imports and aliases in there.

Comment: Thanks @JoséValim. But we cannot get the `__ENV__` of a compiled module, correct?